# libxmlsec1-dev uninstalling npm and npm uninstalling libxmlsec1-dev why?

Tags: npm, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, ubuntu-18.04

I have been installing npm and it removes some SSO packages

```
admin@:~$ sudo apt-get install npm

After this operation, 5,187 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Removing libxmlsec1-dev (1.2.25-1build1) ...
Removing libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4) ...
.
.
.
Setting up nodejs-dev (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Setting up node-gyp (3.6.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up npm (3.5.2-0ubuntu4) ...
```

**while I am trying to install libxmlsec1-dev and it removes npm, I didn't get why is that happening.**

```
admin@:~$ sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
Removing npm (3.5.2-0ubuntu4) ...
Removing node-gyp (3.6.2-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing nodejs-dev (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4) ...
Removing libssl1.0-dev:amd64 (1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.3) ...
.
.
.
Setting up libxmlsec1-dev (1.2.25-1build1) ...
```

Comment: Found the bug/conflict, But did not found the solution.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/npm/+bug/1799261

Comment: you won't have these issues if you use nvm for node version management

Comment: Which version and how it solve my issue?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install npm` is asking for trouble. We can do better than that. Did you actually try any version from `nvm` at all?

Comment: I never tried nvm, but find this https://tecadmin.net/install-nodejs-with-nvm/